# como hacer split a una cadena muy larga en python

Tags: python

Hola quiero hacer split a una cadena muy larga tendrá la siguiente apariencia:

```
"numerodecaracter1" 
&_ 
"numerodecaracter2"
 .. etc..
```

Intente con esto

```
import re

s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"

print '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in re.findall(r'.{1,80}(?:\s+|$)', s))
```

Pero me queda de la siguiente manera:

```
de 1 a 80 caracteres salto de linea
de 1 a 80 caracteres salto de linea
```

Como podría hacer para que se parecierá a la manera que dije :

```
"numerodecaracter1" 
&_ 
"numerodecaracter2"
&_ 
.. etc..
```

Así mi cadena spliteará pero como la manera que indique. Y como último que escribiese en un fichero el resultado en lugar de un `print` pero me da el error:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Codigo:

```
s = "lalalalala" 

#print '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in re.findall(r'.{1,80}(?:\s+|$)', s))

with open('filename.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        myfile.write('\n'.join(line.strip() for line in re.findall(r'.{1,80}(?:\s+|$)', s)))
```

Le quite el enconding y se resolvio lo del write pero cuando uso una cadena larga y con simbolos me rompe toda la cadena por lo  que es importante que pueda usar el encoding.

Captura de como lo quiero:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En Python 2.x `open` no acepta el parámetro `encoding`, esto solo es posible en Python 3.x. Puedes usar  `io.open()` en su lugar o codificar en el `write`. En cuanto a la pregunta en si, ¿como se supone que se debe hacer el split?. ¿Esa cadena (`s`) como deberia quedar finalmente? Es decir, se debe romper cada x caracteres, usando delimitadores como el punto,  etc.

Comment: si exacto se separara de esta manera: cadena salto de linea  &_ cadena salto de linea .. etc.. y tendrá la cadena de x caracteres de una cantidad de caracteres y la cadena tiene que ir entre comillas eso lo que intentaba.

Comment: Eso es la salida que se supone que debes guardar si te he entendido, lo que no tengo claro es **como se parte la cadena**. Quieres partirla cada n caracteres (se corte por donde se corte), partirla cada n palabras, partirla cada n caracteres pero sin partir palabras,  partirla usando los puntos, partirla en x trozos, etc. Debes especificar que pasos seguir para partirla, lo de guardar las subcadenas en el txt es trivial. Seria muy bueno que además pusieras la **salida real** que tu ejemplo `s` deberia tener.

Comment: yo puse una cadena muy larga y no me lo hace no sé porque solo funciona con cadenas cortas.

Comment: la cadena es ; https://paste.ee/p/vE6sl probe con el ejemplo que puse pero no me separa por numero de caracteres y como el ejemplo que puse.

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar el string con codificación no ASCII puedes usar el módulo `io`:

```
import io
import re

s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"

with io.open('filename.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    myfile.write(u'\n&_\n'.join('"'+line.strip()+'"' for line in re.findall(r'.{1,10}(?:\s+|$)', s)))
```

Observación: He cambiado el número de caracteres en la expresión regular para obtener una salida que se pueda mostrar aqui. Cambiala adecuadamente.

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edición:**

Si lo que quieres es partir la cadena cada n caracteres sin importar nada más usa slicing:

```
import io

n = 8 #Numero caracteres por linea
s = "This is a long string that is holding more than 80 characters and thus should be split into several lines. That is if everything is working properly and nicely and all that. No misshaps no typos. No bugs. But I want the code too look good too. That's the problem!"
with io.open('filename.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    myfile.write(u'\n&_\n'.join('"'+s[i:i+n]+'"' for i in range(0, len(s), n)))
```